# How do you change the background colour of a button?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and having trouble with something rather simple. I have set the background colour of my button like this:

```
<Button Background="FF0000"/>
```

I keep getting this error:

> Invalid value for property 'Background': 'FF0000'

Also, if anyone knew the hex code of the background colour in the image below, or how to find it, that would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a pound sign in front of the hex color code. For more information, you can refer to the [documentation for `SoliColorBrush` and XAML attribute usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush?view=net-5.0#xaml-attribute-usage).

```
<Button Background="#FF0000"/>
```

The background color can be found by using an image editor, it is `#393943`.

```
<Button Background="#393943"/>
```

See this [related Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/255647/how-to-pick-a-color-from-an-image) for a variety of ways to pick a color from an image.

Comment: Thanks, is that the purple-ish colour seen in the background of the main form? #202124 appears to be dark, almost black, when I used it.

Comment: @william Sorry, that color was the background of the buttons in the image, I adapted the answer.

Comment: @william I've been doing WPF for more than 10 years, but it's a mistake I make every time. lol